# Boxplot main rectangles delimiter which percentage of data points?

Tags: r, boxplot

I used the command:

```
boxplot(V15~Class,data=trainData, main="V15 value depending on Class", xlab="Class", ylab="V15")
```

I would like to understand which is the percentage of points in the rectangle(s)?

[image]

I mean: if I take all the samples inside the main rectangle, what percentage of the total count of samples will it be?

I found the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html), but cannot figure out this answer.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the question correctly, but since quartiles conventionally define the size of the box, I think the answer should be "50%", i.e. 25% of observations should always be above and below the box.

Comment: @textb Ok; do you see that anywhere in the documentation?

Comment: Not really - I suppose that the creators of the function assumed that boxplots are sufficiently standardized that this would not really be an interesting feature of the implementation (although I think that the definition of the whiskers in different statistics packages may vary).

Comment: Yes, the answer seems to be 50%: http://www.shmoop.com/basic-statistics-probability/box-whisker-plots.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [help text for boxplot](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/graphics/html/boxplot.html), which you refer to, suggest that you should "**See Also** [boxplot.stats](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/boxplot.stats.html) which does the computation". From the "Details" section:

```
The two ‘hinges’ are versions of the first and third quartile, i.e., close to quantile(x, c(1,3)/4).
The hinges equal the quartiles for odd n (where n <- length(x)) and differ for even n.
Whereas the quartiles only equal observations for n %% 4 == 1 (n = 1 mod 4),
the hinges do so additionally for n %% 4 == 2 (n = 2 mod 4), and are in the middle of two observations otherwise.
```

So yes, basically the middle 50% of the values fall inside the box, but the details of the calculation depend on the nature of the data.